# jquery mobile clips text when there is not enough space

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

jquery mobile clips text when there is not enough space, but is there a native way to make it scroll? Is there a plugin or something that could handle this? I can write some custom code, but I'm new to jmobile so why waste time if there is built in functionality :) [image]

Comment: Did you try `overflow: auto` ?

Comment: @Tim Bad wording on my part, I want it to scroll as reveal what is hidden with animation. I could have used white-space: normal; to show hidden text. But that is not my intended question.

Comment: @Tim I'm looking for something like this: http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood sorry. Did you get it to work with jQuery Marquee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could have something like this for window width (450px):

```
<div data-role="header">
<a href="#" data-icon="home">Home</a>
<div class="demo"><marquee scrollamount="6" behavior="alternate" direction="right" width="250"><p>START Lorem epsom</p></marquee></div>                 
<a href="#" data-icon="bars">Menu</a>
</div>
```

with the style:

```
div.demo {         
          padding-left: 100px;        
         }
```

This can help if you have fixed width device support, else need to programatically update the padding-left value and the marquee width.